# How to find child object with property value using Underscorejs and jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

Take the following data:

```
object {
   name: 'foo'
   children: [
      {
         'name': 'cat'
         'color': 'green'
      },
      {
         'name': 'dog'
         'color': 'blue'
      },
      {
         'name': 'bird'
         'color': 'red'
      }
   ]
}
```

How can I use Underscorejs, jQuery and JavaScript to find and select the child where name=dog? I tried using `_.findWhere(objectdata.children,{name:'dog'})`, but that didn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 1):

With Underscore.js you could simply use a filter function such as:

```
var child = _.filter(object.children, obj => obj.name === 'dog');
```

You don't need jQuery for that.

Answer (score 1):

In JQuery you can use filter to get the child object.

```js
var obj = {
   name: 'foo',
   children: [
      {
         'name': 'cat',
         'color': 'green'
      },
      {
         'name': 'dog',
         'color': 'blue'
      },
      {
         'name': 'bird',
         'color': 'red'
      }
   ]
};

console.log(obj.children.filter(function(e){return e.name == "dog";})[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```