# Traversing through Javascript Object and checking property has child with data

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

I'm trying to traverse through the above object to see if a contact has membership to a particular list.

For example, if user is a member of the list with the id of `2022`, then display users first name (also from the object).

### What I've tried:

```js
    var data = {
  "id": 12345,
  "is-contact": true,

  "firstname": {
    value: "Freddy"
  },
  "list-memberships": [
    {
      "list-id": 2022,
        "is-member": true
    },
    {
      "list-id": 5033,
      "is-member": true
    }
  ]

}

    var list_memberships = "list-memberships";
    var list_id = "list_id";

    // is member a list of this list
    var check_against_list = 2022;

    // trying to get first name
    console.log(data.firstname.value); // logs undefined (Cannot read property 'value' of undefined)

    // trying to check through each list-membership item to see if a list with the id of check_against_list (2022) exists
    var child = _.filter(data.list_memberships, obj => data.list_memberships.list_id === check_against_list);
```

I've adapted the following using [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41242912/how-to-find-child-object-with-property-value-using-underscorejs-and-jquery)

Comment: `list-memberships` looks like it should be an array.

Comment: @luekbaja You can, but you have to wrap the keys/names in qoutes -> `"list-id": ...`

Comment: The syntax error in your fiddle should be your first starting point...

Comment: That data is invalid, missing comma after firstname, as @Andreas mentioned keys should be wrapped, list-memeberships has no keys

Answer (score 1):

Yo have some problems in your array: commas and `-` char in variable names, which is not right. Take a look at this code

```js
var data = {
  id: 12345,
  iscontact: true,

  firstname: {
    value: "Freddy"
  },

  listmemberships: [
    {
      listid: 2022,
      ismember: true
    },
    {
      listid: 5033,
      ismember: true
    },
  ]
};

// is member a list of this list
var check_against_list = 2022;

// trying to get first name
console.log(data.firstname.value);

// trying to check through each list-membership item to see if a list with the id of check_against_list (2022) exists
var child = data.listmemberships.filter(obj => obj.listid === check_against_list);

// List exist, if this array > 0
if(child.length > 0) {
  console.log("Exist!");
  console.log(child);
}
```